# Eventos sencillos sobre arreglos completos

Tags: c++, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++

Necesito ayuda por favor para el siguiente programa en C++:
Dado un array de N enteros con valores iniciales, queremos ejecutar sobre él una secuencia de M eventos de los siguientes tipos:

Evento de tipo 0: asignar 0 a todos los elementos del array.
Evento de tipo 1: incrementar todos los elementos del array.

Entrada:
El entero N seguido de los N enteros del array. Posteriormente, el entero M seguido de los M eventos que se desean ejecutar. Se puede asumir que 1≤N, M≤2x10^5 y que los valores iniciales de los elementos del array están entre 0 y 1000.

Salida:
Una secuencia de N enteros denotando el estado final del array.

Ya he hecho mi código, pero OmegaUp me dice que mi código es demasiado lento (TLE), ¿cómo podría hacer para obtener el resultado mucho más rápido?
Saludos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Lectura de la entrada
    int N, M;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> arreglo(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cin >> arreglo[i];
    }
    cin >> M;

    // Contador de eventos de tipo 1
    int eventos_tipo_1 = 0;

    // Procesamiento de los eventos
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        int tipo_evento;
        cin >> tipo_evento;
        if (tipo_evento == 0) {
            // Evento de tipo 0: resetear todos los elementos del arreglo a 0
            fill(arreglo.begin(), arreglo.end(), 0);
            eventos_tipo_1 = 0; // Reiniciar el contador de eventos de tipo 1
        } else {
            // Evento de tipo 1: incrementar el contador de eventos de tipo 1
            eventos_tipo_1++;
        }
    }

    // Aplicar eventos de tipo 1 al arreglo
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        arreglo[i] += eventos_tipo_1;
    }

    // Salida del estado final del arreglo
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cout << arreglo[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola de nuevo, en vez de crear una nueva pregunta deberías haber editado tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/616282/tiempo-de-ejecuci%c3%b3n) y agregar el nuevo código, ya que es la misma pregunta solo que con un nuevo intento de solucionar el problema.

Comment: Dicho esto, veo que has aplicado las ideas que deje en mi comentario en tu anterior pregunta, aún hay margen de mejora, lo más obvio es que la salida que pide es "Una secuencia de N enteros denotando el estado final del array", en ningún sitio dice que tengas que modificar realmente el array de entrada... El ciclo "Aplicar eventos de tipo 1" y el fill() no son necesarios, calculalo todo al imprimir, es más, si hay un evento cero ni siquiera necesitas leer el array....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podemos darnos cuenta que si reestablecemos el arreglo, no importa cuántas veces lo hayamos incrementado previamente:

- Todos sus elementos serán 0.
- Todos sus elementos serán iguales.

Inteligentemente, podemos obtener todos los eventos antes de efectuar las operaciones correspondientes y decidir ignorar o no los valores iniciales.

```
bool reestablecer = false;
int incrementos = 0;

// Procesamiento de los eventos
for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    int tipo_evento;
    cin >> tipo_evento;
    if (tipo_evento == 0) {
        reestablecer = true;
        incrementos = 0;
    } else {
        incrementos++;
    }
}

if (reestablecer) {
    // Salida del estado final
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cout << incrementos << " ";
    } 
    cout << endl;
}
else {
    // Aplicar eventos de tipo 1 al arreglo
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        arreglo[i] += incrementos;
    }

    // Salida del estado final del arreglo
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cout << arreglo[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

Teniendo en cuenta que los números están entre 0 y 1000, podrías utilizar un tipo más pequeño como `short`. Es posible que el programa sea más rápido ya que al ocupar menos espacio, más cantidad de números pueden entrar en la caché.

También puedes probar de desactivar la sincronización con la entrada/salida de C, según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12762166/13419694) así es más rápido.

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```